# Make slices size

Tags: go, allocation

In Golang you can allocate memory for a slice with the below syntax :

```
my_slice := make( []int, 0 )
```

And then later on I can add elements with the built-in append function as :

```
my_slice := append(my_slice, 23)
```

My question is, what's the difference between giving that zero ( or 2 or 5 or whatever) when "making" the slice if later on we can keep adding items as long as we wan?

Is there a performance bonus by trying to guess the capacity that slice will end up having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the memory for the slice is allocated upfront and `len(mySlice)` returns the total slice length.

Performance wise it is beneficial to allocate the size upfront because when you call `a = append(a, n)` the following occurs:

- It calls the builtin append function and for that it first copies the `a` slice (slice header, backing array is not part of the header), and it has to create a temporary slice for the variadic parameter which will contain the value `n`.
- Then it has to reslice `a` if it has enough capacity like `a = a[:len(a)+1]` - which involves assigning the new slice to `a` inside the append function. If a would not have big enough capacity to do the append "in-place" then a new array would have to be allocated, content from slice copied, and then the assign / append be executed.
- Then assigns `n` to a `[len(a)-1]`.
- Then returns the new slice from the append function, and this new slice is assigned to the local variable `a`.

Compared to `a[i] = n` which is a simple assignment.

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments
- https://blog.golang.org/slices

Comment: The built-in `append` function is optimized by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna answer that with following example:

```
func main(){
    var n int =  1000000
    var testSlice1 = []int{}
    var testSlice2 = make([]int , 0 , n)

    fmt.Printf("Total time without Preallocation: %v \n" , timeloop(testSlice1, n))
    fmt.Printf("Total time with Preallocation: %v \n" , timeloop(testSlice2 , n))
    

}


func timeloop(slice []int , n int) (time.Duration){
    var t0 = time.Now()
    for len(slice) < n {
        slice = append(slice  , 1 )

    }

    return time.Since(t0)
}
```

in the timeloop function, we are just appending elements into the existing slice.
testslice1 is not preallocated, whereas testslice2 is preallocated
appending values from 0 to million.
Output:

```
Total time without Preallocation: 23.9319ms 
Total time with Preallocation: 4.373ms
```

we see its approximately 6 times faster with preallocation.
Because without preallocation capacity of the underlying array is changed and a new array is created in the memory where 2 times the old capacity can be allocated continuously. Number of reallocations = log2(capacity after reallocation) - 1
We get 21 for a million.

Answer (score -1):

> My question is, what's the difference between giving that zero ( or 2 or 5 or whatever) when "making" the slice if later on we can keep adding items as long as we wan?

A not appropriate allocation can cause re-allocation.

> Is there a performance bonus by trying to guess the capacity that slice will end up having?

yes, re-allocation will lead to additional copy on slice.

> Slice: The size specifies the length. The capacity of the slice is
>   equal to its length. A second integer argument may be provided to
>   specify a different capacity; it must be no smaller than the length.
>
> For example, make([]int, 0, 10) allocates an underlying array of size
>   10 and returns a slice of length 0 and capacity 10 that is backed by
>   this underlying array.

copy from go doc.

In my view. Slice is **like a pointer with length and capacity** in c/c++. Append to a slice will append elements after the offset on that pointer. The capacity is the total sequential space size. Once the `capacity`- `allocated` space is not enough, append will cause a re-allocation and a copy on the slice.

> `make(s, 1)`

go will do more than you think:

1. Allocate a sequential space larger than the size you give (same in c++ vector) to avoid the re-allocation which can cause low performance.
2. Initialize the size you give in make. (RAII)
3. Once reallocation happened, go will allocate a twice size sequential space and copy the old slice to that place. This will also low down the performance.

To avoid the reallocation happen, we can give the optional capacity arguments in `make` to tell the go we need a bigger space.